# Can GCC cross-compile for AIX?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, aix

I'm trying to build GCC as a cross-compiler for AIX; the host and the build platforms are Linux x86_64, the target is powerpc-aix5.2.0.  I've managed to cross-compile Binutils 2.20.1 and GCC 4.4.7 with native AIX 6.1 headers (from */usr/include*) and libs (only */usr/lib/{crt0.o,crt0_64.o,libc.a,libc_r.a,libpthreads.a}*).  Then gcc correctly cross-builds simple C code (such as "Hello, world!") into stand-alone executables but it refuses to cross-build shared objects:

> collect2: init function found in object *< path to cross-compiled libgcc_s.a >*

I tried using newer versions of Binutils up to 2.26 with the same result.

Then I found the following [comment](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31033#c8):

> Binutils was updated to support AIX 4.3.3, but has not been maintained, improved, or updated for AIX 5.  It can do simple things, but does not fully support more advanced features.  For instance, some aspects of shared object creation are not complete.

So I tried re-building the above toolchain with target=powerpc-aix4.3.0 (the only difference this time was that I configured GCC with *--disable-multilib* to avoid the error "Unrecognized opcode: `fmsub'").  I tried both Binutils 2.20.1 and Binutils 2.26 but I still got the error *init function found in object libgcc_s.a*.

Now I wonder if there is a version of AIX for which cross-compilation, esp. of shared objects, is supported by GCC and Binutils.

Comment: Why not compile with on AIX? It is a problematic enough platform in itself, you don't have to make it even more problematic with cross-compiling.

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy Plenty of reasons, here are some:  Corporate network policy forbids antiquated/unpatched operating systems from being connected to the company network. You want to use a funky new build tool that isn't supported or easy to compile on that platform.  You want the build to happen faster and the old hardware is limiting your build speed.  Your hardware is failing and you don't have the budget or inclination to replace it. You can't virtualize your build machines and you need to.  The old hardware/OS doesn't work with your backup software.

Comment: Well, using such cross-compiled binaries is always a gamble: it will either work or not. (To be frank, the same goes for every other programs, too.)

Comment: One should stick to the IBM compiler (not even use GCC), for the lowest risk.  However right now I'm staring at ~80 instances of errclear and wondering how they got there, if they are important, and wondering why one test throws up "Invalid file system control data detected", instead of concentrating on compiling/debugging code which is what I'm supposed to be doing, so I can identify with the question.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is "no".  As the comment says, the GCC version of the linker (ld) does not really work for AIX.  All of the open source code that I compile on AIX I use GCC but I use the native ld command.

Comment: I thought that the comment implied AIX 4.3.3 was *fully* supported and it was AIX 5 where only simple things were supported.